# A treasure has been found

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Once upon a time, in a remote and small village situated far away from the hustle and bustle of the cities, lived an old farmer who had a farm. During his teenage years, he found love and tied the knot with a woman from India and decided to stay back in her country. Together, they lived a contented and blissful life.

While cultivating his farmland one day, the farmer stumbled upon a valuable gemstone. Being a father of 10 children, he wished to notify all of them about his discovery. In order to maintain confidentiality, he decided to send a mysterious letter to each of his offspring.

Following is the letter he sent -

[image]

*Three questions for you -*

***1. What are the names of his children?

2. What gemstone did he found?

3. What is his name?***

P.S. Not really required, but just in case you want to confirm that the names you have found are correct, use [this](https://www.indianhindunames.com/alphabetical-order-indian-names.htm).

Comment: Apparently, 3 of my colleagues at work share the same names with 3 of his kids.

Comment: @Billyb lol Yeah, they are pretty common names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The names of his children are as follows:

> - **E**kv**ee**ra
>  - Urm**i**la
>  - Lok**e**sh
>  - N**i**kh**i**l
>  - **O**mar
>  - Ap**e**ksha
>  - **I**sh**i**ta
>  - Mand**ee**p
>  - Tr**i**pt**i**
>  - R**o**hit

The gemstone he found is:

> **[Tourmaline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourmaline)**, solved via anagram of the first initial of each child after solving the correct names. Credit to Billyb for helping.

His name is:

> MacDonald, because [old MacDonald had a farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_MacDonald_Had_a_Farm).
>  Also because the missing vowels are ordered EIEIO.

Comment: Great job. You got all the names right except one. You got his name right though there's another explanation to it. You will get it when you find the correct names for all. The name of the gemstone is incorrect.

Comment: The stone was a stab at it, I hadn't come up with something more grounded. I found the other explanation for his name, since rot13(Gur zvffvat ibjryf tb RVRVB. Juvpu jbhyq znxr gur vapbeerpg anzr Nzne npghnyyl Bzne.)

Comment: Yup, there you go :)

Comment: @Alexander Initials of the names anagram to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourmaline)

Comment: @Billyb Great find! Beat me to it. I was trying to anagram the initials given without filling in the vowels.